# Writing dictionary list values to a text file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have the following dictionary that contains a list for each of its values

```
dictionary = { 
               0 : [2, 5] 
               1 : [1, 4]
               2 : [3]
             }
```

I need to output the values in a file like this

```
2 5
1 4
3
```

At the last digit of each row i need to have a space.

I have already tried to use this code

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for value in dictionary.values():
        f.write('{}\n'.format(value))
```

so i want to omit the [] and the , of the output.

I have also tried to save the values of dictionary into a lists of list and then handle list instead of dictionary. But it's not the wisest thing i guess. Numbers are also saved on wrong order and brackets and commas are save too.

```
a = list(dictionary.values())
for i in a:
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in a:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

because i get this output

```
[3, 2]
[5, 1]
[4]
```

Comment: `' '.join(value)`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first version is pretty close, so let's improve on that.

What you can do, is use a list comprehension to iterate through and convert each integer into a string. Then call `join` on the resulting list of strings.

Something like the following should work:

```
dictionary = { 
    0: [2, 5],
    1: [1, 4],
    2: [3]
}

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for value in dictionary.values():
        print(' '.join([str(s) for s in value]), file=f)
```

Side note: I've replaced `f.write` with `print`, to avoid manually specifying a newline character.

If you want a trailing space character on each line, you can either do this using f-strings:

```
print(f"{' '.join([str(s) for s in value])} ", file=f)
```

or traditional string concatenation:

```
print(' '.join([str(s) for s in value]) + ' ', file=f)
```

Comment: Just join the items of the list with a space, don’t try to string-manipulate its representation.

Comment: @deceze does my latest edit address your concern?

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help. It is not 100% necessary but if you can make the code to give me an extra space after the last number of each row i would be glad. :)

Comment: @condoriano seems a bit strange that you'd want extra trailing spaces, but in any case, I've added a few approaches to that in the answer

Comment: It is a bit strange yes. It' just that i don't want to mess with the rest of the code that reads the txt files that get an extra trailing space on each row by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the output you want:

```py
a = list(dictionary.values())
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in a:
        f.write(' '.join(item) + "\n")
```

**Update:** I had better go with the idea from @deceze

Comment: I get this error on your suggestion. SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here